# formik + yup validation schema not working properly in MUI Dialog (multi step)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I am trying to implement a multi step dialog using formik, yup and MUI dialog.

My multi step dialog consists of 5 steps and in each step there's a number of Mui components (select, input).

But every time I type something in one input a validation error is triggered on all the other inputs in the current step.

I made my validation schema to be array based so I can use a specific validation schema for each step `validationSchema[currentStep]`

I think the problem is from the way I set my validation schema but I couldn't find another way to implement this, since I need to implement as multi step dialog

This is the validation schema with yup

```
export const businessContactsSchema = [
  yup.object().shape({
    type: yup.string().required('Type field is required'),
  }),
  yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required('Name field is required'),
    type: yup.string().required('Type field is required'),
    phone: yup.string().required('Phone field is required'),
    email: yup.string().email('Must be a valid email address').required('Email field is required'),
    invoiceEmail: yup
      .string()
      .email('Must be a valid email address')
      .required('Invoice Email field is required'),
    chamberCommerceNumber: yup.string().required('Chamber of Commerce Number field is required'),
    contactName: yup.string().required('Contact name field is required'),
    iban: yup.string().required('IBAN field is required'),
    source: yup.string(),
    vatNumber: yup.string().required('VAT number field is required'),
  }),
  yup.object().shape({
    contactAddress: yup.object().shape({
      placeId: yup.string().required('Location field is required'),
      building: yup.string(),
      floor: yup.string(),
      zipCode: yup.string().required('Zip Code field is required'),
      apartmentNumber: yup.string().required('Apartment Number field is required'),
    }),
  }),
  yup.object().shape({
    billingAddress: yup.object().shape({
      placeId: yup.string().required('Location field is required'),
      building: yup.string(),
      floor: yup.string(),
      zipCode: yup.string().required('Zip Code field is required'),
      apartmentNumber: yup.string().required('Apartment Number field is required'),
    }),
  }),
  yup.object().shape({
    comments: yup.string().nullable().notRequired(),
  }),
];
```

and this is the formik implementation

```
<Formik
      innerRef={formikFormRef}
      enableReinitialize
      initialValues={businessTypeInitialState}
      validationSchema={businessContactsSchema}
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
        if (isLastStep) {
          let payload = {
            ...values,
            record_type_id: contactRecordType === 'Corporate' ? '1' : '2',
            contact_id: props.openDialog?.data?.contactId,
            same_address: isSameAddress,
            billingAddressId: props.openDialog?.data?.billingAddress.addressId,
            contactAddressId: props.openDialog?.data?.contactAddress.addressId,
          };
          if (props.openDialog?.dialogType === 'addContact') {
            addContactMutation(payload, {
              onSuccess: (data) => {
                if (data.statusCode === 200) {
                  queryClient.invalidateQueries('contacts');
                  setContactData(data);
                  setCurrentStep(5);
                  resetForm();
                } else if (data.statusCode === 403)
                  setAPIResponse({ message: data.message, code: data.statusCode });
                else setAPIResponse({ message: 'There was a server error', code: data.statusCode });
              },
            });
          } else if (props.openDialog?.dialogType === 'editContact') {
            updateContactMutation(payload, {
              onSuccess: (data) => {
                if (data.statusCode === 200) {
                  queryClient.invalidateQueries('contactDetails');
                  setCurrentStep(0);
                  props.onClose();
                }
              },
            });
          }
        } else {
          if (isSameAddress && currentStep === 2) return setCurrentStep(currentStep + 2);
          return setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
        }
      }}
    >
      {({ dirty }) => (
        <StyledDialog
          open={isDialogOpen()}
          onClose={handleCloseDialog}
          isEdited={dirty}
          fullScreen={isMobile()}
          width="1064px"
          height="725px"
        >
          <DialogContent>
            {isLoading ? (
              <div className="grid place-content-center h-full">
                <CircularProgress color="error" />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="flex gap-8 h-full">
                {currentStep !== 5 && (
                  <div className="hidden sm:flex items-center gap-8 w-[25%]">
                    <div className="relative flex flex-col justify-between h-5/6">
                      <div className="absolute right-6 h-full border border-[#F6F4F4] z-10"></div>
                      {contactDialogSteps.map((step) => (
                        <div
                          key={step.stepIndex}
                          className="flex justify-center items-center gap-5 z-50"
                        >
                          <div
                            className={`w-full flex justify-end text-[16px] text-[#8E8E8E] ${
                              currentStep === step.stepIndex && 'font-semibold text-black'
                            }`}
                          >
                            {step.stepName}
                          </div>
                          <div
                            className={`transition ease-in-out delay-150 p-4 ${
                              currentStep === step.stepIndex ? 'bg-[#EA3323]' : 'bg-[#8E8E8E]'
                            } rounded-full`}
                          >
                            <img src={step.icon} />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>

                    <div className="relative flex flex-col justify-between h-5/6">
                      <div className="absolute h-full right-[7px] z-10 border border-[#F6F4F4]"></div>
                      {contactDialogSteps.map((step) => (
                        <div key={step.stepIndex} className="p-1 rounded-full flex bg-[#F6F4F4]">
                          <span
                            className={`${
                              currentStep === step.stepIndex ? 'bg-[#EA3323]' : 'bg-[#8E8E8E]'
                            } w-2 h-2 z-50 rounded-full transition ease-in-out delay-150`}
                          ></span>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}

                <Form
                  className={`${
                    currentStep === 5 ? 'w-full' : 'w-full sm:w-[75%]'
                  } flex flex-col gap-4 justify-between h-full p-2`}
                >
                  <div className="m-auto w-full overflow-auto">
                    <LocusContextProvider
                      dialogType={props.openDialog?.dialogType}
                      dropdownValues={data?.data}
                      APIResponse={APIResponse}
                    >
                      {currentStep === 0 && (
                        <ContactType
                          contactRecordType={contactRecordType}
                          onRecordTypeSelect={(type) => setContactRecordType(type)}
                        />
                      )}
                      {currentStep === 1 &&
                        (contactRecordType === 'Corporate' ? (
                          <CorporateGeneralInfo />
                        ) : (
                          <IndividualGeneralInfo />
                        ))}

                      {currentStep === 2 && (
                        <ContactAddress
                          onCheckBoxToggle={() => setIsSameAddress(!isSameAddress)}
                          isChcked={isSameAddress}
                        />
                      )}

                      {currentStep === 3 && !isSameAddress && <BillingAddress />}
                      {currentStep === 4 && <Comments />}
                      {currentStep === 5 && <SuccessStep contactData={contactData} />}
                    </LocusContextProvider>
                  </div>

                  <div className="self-end flex gap-4">
                    {currentStep !== 0 && currentStep !== 5 && (
                      <div
                        onClick={handleDecreaseStep}
                        className="flex justify-center gap-4 bg-[#F6F4F4] cursor-pointer text-[#8E8E8E] rounded-2xl font-bold p-3 w-32 text-center"
                      >
                        <img src={backArrow} />
                        Back
                      </div>
                    )}

                    {currentStep !== 5 && (
                      <StyledButton type="submit">
                        {addContactLoading || updateContactLoading ? (
                          <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                        ) : isLastStep ? (
                          'Submit'
                        ) : (
                          'Next'
                        )}
                      </StyledButton>
                    )}

                    {currentStep === 5 && (
                      <StyledButton
                        onClick={() =>
                          navigate(`/contact-overview/${contactData?.data.contactId}/details`, {
                            state: { recordType: contactData?.data?.recordType },
                          })
                        }
                      >
                        Go To Details
                      </StyledButton>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </Form>
              </div>
            )}
          </DialogContent>
        </StyledDialog>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

any help would be appreciated